# Htaccess deny specific get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, get

I want to do deny access to specific ip. I tried this htaccess code but didn't worked:

```
<Files "index.php?action=deny">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from XXXX
Allow from all
</Files>
```

where XXXX is an ip address. how can I do something like that, so it will deny only specific get parameter and not the whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern in `Files` directive is misleading. If you want to match the URL with `action=deny` query argument; you'd need to use [`<Location>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location):

```
<Location /index.php?action=deny>
```

Comment: Location doesn't match the query string

Answer (score 3):

In 2.4, use  to check the query string

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /action=deny/">
  Require all denied
</If>
```

In 2.2, use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=deny
RewriteRule index.php - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=deny$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =11.22.33.44
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [F]
```

Replace `11.22.33.44` with your actual IP address